# Make sub-string of string bold which is populated from jekyll variable

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, liquid

On my page I would like part of a string to be bold, however the string value is created from a Jekyll variable. Effectively, I want to pre-process the string with some function where the jekyll variable is the input.

In my main html file I have:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% include archive.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

Inside `archive.html` I have:

```
<p> {{ post.var }} </p>
```

I'm assuming javascript is the way to go about this using a function along the lines of:

```
function makeSubStrBold(str) {
  var substr = "something"
  var strRegExp = new RegExp(substr, 'g');
  return str.replace(strRegExp, '<b>'+substr+'</b>');
}
```

So if `post.var = "this is something"`, what gets actually displayed in html is `"this is <b> something </b>"`

How could I use this javascript function to pre-process the string from the jekyll variable? Is this maybe possible in css?